# Wireless signal drops on Lenovo G series

Tags: wireless

This question was asked before, but it went unanswered so I thought I might give it a try and ask.

I have a Lenovo G series laptop which came with Windows 7 64bit. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 recently and I've been having this problem with  my wireless signal. I had this problem before, so I had stop using Ubuntu.

I got back into it, did a fresh reinstall of xubuntu 12.10, and still have this problem. When I'm near the router, I have perfect wireless signal. It's at 100% strength. As soon as I enter my room which can't be no more than 20 feet away, I lose signal. I lose my internet. And I can't connect again. I have my drivers up to date and my modem software is up to date too. My modem is one of those wireless modems, which has a built-in router inside. It's a 2wire 2701 series. Although I'm still new to Linux, I'll try and post all the information needed to debug this problem.

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c1
       serial: b8:70:f4:43:c6:04
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:40 memory:90100000-9013ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:de:2b:3f:79:00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k ip=192.168.1.81 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:90000000-9000ffff

$ sudo lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
usb_storage            61750  0 
bnep                   18259  2 
rfcomm                 47865  4 
bluetooth             219320  10 bnep,rfcomm
parport_pc             32867  0 
ppdev                  17114  0 
arc4                   12574  2 
joydev                 17614  0 
fglrx                5280770  108 
uvcvideo               82215  0 
ath9k                 147066  0 
videobuf2_core         36108  1 uvcvideo
mac80211              583047  1 ath9k
videodev              129966  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_hda_codec_conexant    62409  1 
snd_hda_intel          38509  6 
kvm_amd                60123  0 
ath9k_common           14054  1 ath9k
snd_hda_codec         140413  2 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
ath9k_hw              417454  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
snd_hwdep              13669  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102478  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
kvm                   437135  1 kvm_amd
snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
ath                    24124  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
snd_rawmidi            30418  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61931  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
psmouse                92376  0 
snd                    69534  20 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
cfg80211              208484  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
soundcore              12681  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18799  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
microcode              23018  0 
serio_raw              13216  0 
sp5100_tco             13792  0 
i2c_piix4              13505  0 
k10temp                13174  0 
ideapad_laptop         18597  0 
amd_iommu_v2           19199  1 fglrx
video                  19468  0 
sparse_keymap          13891  1 ideapad_laptop
mac_hid                13254  0 
lp                     17800  0 
parport                46563  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
atl1c                  41886  0
```

If you need anymore information, please let me know. Thank you for your time.
EDIT: I forgot to mention, I have the latest 3.7 kernel.